# How to plot line chart with more than one variable in X and Y axis

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, linechart

I have a data set as shown below .I need to craete a line chart from this in such a way that all the columns shown in yellow color should come in the X axis and columns in Green color needs to come in the Y axis.May I know how to approch this.

[image]

I am expecting a plot like this shown below

[image]

[image: chart obtained after running the code]

Chart obtained after running the code

Comment: Kindly take a look at my answer and let me know if it helps you.

Comment: Sure I will check it and let you know. Thank you very much. One more doubt if I hover the mouse along the plot will it show details.

Comment: You would need to use ggplot for that, and add the mouseover option

Comment: I know that opinions are off-topic on SO, but in my opinion, a line chart is not appropriate for this data. The x-axis variables are categorical, so the data points should not be connected, a side-by-side bar chart (or lollipop chart) would be more appropriate. But in any case, I think this is too much data to show in a single graph. Displaying the data with small multiples (e.g. by device) could be a first step and aggregating it in some way (e.g. plotting only the differences of 3.07 vs 2.4 MHz) could be a second step. What is the key message you want to communicate about this data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try with the following? As I stated in my comments, you would need to create an index value from the 3 columns you wish to use as X-axis:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pylab import rcParams
rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 12, 5
df = pd.read_excel(file_location).ffill()
sns.lineplot(x=df['Device_ID'].astype(str)+df['Temp(deg)'].astype(str)+'-'+df['Supply[v]'].astype(str),
             y=df[2.4],color='r')
sns.lineplot(x=df['Device_ID'].astype(str)+df['Temp(deg)'].astype(str)+'-'+df['Supply[v]'].astype(str),
             y=df[3.07],color='b')
plt.legend(['2.4','3.07'])
plt.ylabel('Frequency[MHz]')
plt.tick_params(axis='x',labelsize=8)
```

This outputs:

[image]

Comment: Your code is working. Please find the image obtained. Actually, my excel contains 460 rows.so X-axis is not clear in the plot . Could you please tell me how to improve the readability?

Comment: Well, you could make incredibly long, by fixingfigsize and/or reducing the font too.

Comment: I tried with different sizes but the x axis is the same as I showed in the attached figure. Not able to read anything. May I know is there any way to dynamically adjust the axis

Comment: That's strange, I've searched for a dynamic way of doing it, but couldn't find anything, I'm sorry. You are modifying this line of code, right? `rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 12, 5`

Comment: Yes same line,I made it 25,25 but still X axis is not visible.

Comment: if you don't mind could you please tell me how to write your code for Plotly

Comment: If I can find some for it I'll do ! Can't promise I'll do it right now

Comment: Sure please take your time,meanwhile I will also try

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

plt.plot(df[x], df[y_1], label="y_1")
plt.plot(df[x], df[y_2], label="y_2")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: As you say, this is how you would 'approach' this. If you have a more specific example of the end result, I can show exactly how to do that as well.

Comment: I need to plot the above data only(I showed a portion of it). Please take X-axis data from the Yellow columns and Y-axis data from the green columns . If you can show the complete code with those data it is well and good. I am new to this. Thank you

Comment: I understand what you are saying. But, it is not as simple as it that sounds. For example, do you want subplots? Is it color driven? Label driven? Should more than one Device_ID be on a subplot? That's why I say I need an example of the final result. I'm happy to give you code to copy and paste, but I don't want to create something that you don't like. Or, something that you haven't given at least a drawing of.

Comment: Thank you. I edited my question. Added a plot . I am expecting a similar plot like that